# How to run a mini-buffer command from interpreter

Tags: help

I think this might be a duplicate but I can't figure out how to run this:

```lisp
(man emacs)[cursor] [C-x][C-e]
```

Error I get back:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable gpg)
  (man gpg)
  eval((man gpg) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

I'm trying to put a lisp expression in a file to open the man page in Emacs. So I can save an expression like this in my notes, and then open the man page in Emacs by running eval on the line.

I thonght it might be `(man 'emacs)`, but It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using any of the following examples, with double quotes around the MAN-ARGS:

```
(man "emacs")
```

or

```
(man "gpg")
```

or

```
(man "chmod(2)")
```

I don't have the `gpg` manual installed, but the other two examples do generate a manual buffer ...